# How to say "You can't get there from here" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

How would you translate:

> You can't get there from here.

Here's my attempt:

> Illuc hinc advenire non potes.

Is there a better way to express that?

Comment: Is it "illuc" = to there, "hinc" = "from here"?

Comment: @tony. OK. Thanks!

Comment: Well let's not give up all hope just yet. There's still a few States left to declare.

Comment: @Expediti Bipes: Alternatively, "non hinc proficiscereris." = "You shouldn't start from here."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally, I'd simplify somewhat and use an impersonal passive: *hinc illuc non (per)venitur*, 'There is no arriving to that place from this place.' Or, I'd use what you've done but change the verb to *possis* to indicate a generic 'you' (i.e., 'one').

Otherwise, I believe what you've done is correct. The pairing of *hinc* and *illuc* in this way is well attested. For example, here are fragments 246–8 of Ennius (from the tragedy *Iphigenia*, quoted in Aulus Gellius, *Noctes Atticae* 19.10.12):

> hoc idem est; em neque domi nunc nos nec militiae sumus:
> imus huc, hinc illuc; cum illuc ventum est, ire illinc lubet.
> incerte errat animus, praeterpropter uitam vivitur.
>
> It's the same with us. Look, now we're neither at home nor abroad: we go here, from here to there; when we've arrived there, it's pleasing leave there. Our mind wanders without direction, the life we live is an approximation of life.

Comment: A classic Ennius :)

Comment: @cnread: Literally; "praeterpropter vitam vivitur" = "more-or-less life (subject) is lived (passive verb)"; why is "life" given in the accusative, "vitam"?

Comment: @tony, I suppose it would be accusative showing extent of time. Still, in the OLD entry for praeterpropter, this passage is cited, and '(s.v.l.)' – short for  '(si vera lectio)' – is printed after the word vitam; so the editors at Oxford have doubts about the form too.

Answer (score 7):

Short and crisp suggestion:

> Hinc illuc iter nullum (est).